# Trying to read from private maven repo gives an authentication error

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I just setup a private maven repository for out project team and I am having trouble getting authenticated.
I used this guide to set it up: https://github.com/renaudcerrato/appengine-maven-repository

I started off getting errors trying to deploy artifacts to the server but after I put this info into settings.xml I was able to upload it without any problems:

```
  <servers>
      <server>
      <id>freakyville</id>
      <username>admin</username>
      <password>passwordhere</password>
      <configuration>
      </configuration>
    </server>
  </servers>
```

I then tried to use it like this in my pom.xml

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>freakyville</id>
        <url>https://freakyville.appspot.com/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.freakyville</groupId>
        <artifactId>Utils</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

But that gives me this error:

```
org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.impl.auth.HttpAuthenticator handleAuthChallenge
WARNING: Malformed challenge: Authentication challenge is empty
```

I tried googling and found out that I might need http headers so I added those like this:

```
  <server>
  <id>freakyville</id>
  <username>admin</username>
  <password>---</password>
  <configuration>
    <httpHeaders>
        <property>
            <name>Authorization</name>
            <!-- Base64-encoded "admin:admin" can be encoded online at https://www.base64encode.org/ -->
            <value>Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=</value>
        </property>
    </httpHeaders>
  </configuration>
</server>
```

where i changed the 'YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=' part to the encryptet version of our user and password, still with the same error though.

Anyone have a solution to why this is?

Comment: Assuming you have read [these steps](https://github.com/matthewcosgrove/poc-gcp-maven-private-repo). Check that the `settings.xml` file where you added it is used by the Maven you are using (in IDE it is specified under Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | **User settings file**). They also say that this configuration is not reuired by maven 3.3.3 or older. So you can try install use it (Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | **Maven home directory**).

Comment: Wow you were right, somehow I had two settings files. I changed intellij to use the correct one and now it works - Thanks!